# The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, error-handling, exit-code

While computing the sum of [Leaders in an array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/leaders-in-an-array/) using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), I encountered an error that said: *"The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" terminated with exit code: 1."*

My C++ implementation goes as follows:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int leader_func(int arr[], int n)
{
  int sum=0;
  int max=arr[n-1];
  for (int i = n-2; i>=0; i--)
   {
     if (max<arr[i])
      {
         sum+=arr[i];
      }
   }
return sum;
}

int main()
{
int arr[4]={33,7,21,14};
int n=4;
cout<<leader_func(arr, n);
return 0;
}
```

The expected output is: `54` (i.e. 33 + 21).

The actual result I received: `The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.`

What could be the possible reasons? And how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Maybe use `#include <iostream>` instead of the dreadful `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`? See: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073)

Comment: ... you may be getting some kind of 'clash' between your `max` variable and something (like `std::max`?) defined in one of the zillion headers you implicitly include with that appalling first line.

Answer (score 0):

change
project file -> settings -> post build setup -> add \ (at the end) to the xcopy message